# Excel VBA code for SumIF function

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

Hi I am writing VBA code such that -

If the value of cell M1 is found in any cell Value of Range D1:D20 then Find the sum of corresponding cell values in Range C1:C20. 
But I am getting confused as to how to use the function and pass the parameters. This is what I have tried now, but it does not work

```
Private Sub FindTotal()
    Dim Temp2Sheet As Worksheet

    Set Temp2Sheet = Sheets("Temp2")
    Temp2Sheet.Activate

    Dim temp As String
    temp = Temp2Sheet.Range("M1").Value
    Temp2Sheet.Range("N1").Value = Application.SumIf(Range("D1:D20"), "" * "&temp&" * "", Range("C1:C20"))

End Sub
```

I need to extend same logic for Range M1 to how many ever values are there is Column M and it is dynamic. The totals will appear in Column N in the corresponding cell of column M. Like M1 total will be in N1, and so on

My main confusion here is how do I pass the temp variable as parameter 2 of SUMIF function and add wild cards (**)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error?  I'm pretty sure that if you want to include the double quotes you need three double quotes, like so """.  That being said, I think you'd be better off abandoning the SUMIF formula and iterating through the rows and using an If...Then statement.

Comment: There is no error ...but nothing is getting set in Cell N1. I am sure it is because the matching criteria is not correct. I just wanted to avoid the traditional Looping method, this is much easier but still that is my backup option

Comment: Also, do you want a space before and after the wildcards?  Try this:     """*" & temp & "*"""

Comment: Doesn't appear to be showing up correctly in comment, I will add it in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I mean by triple quotes:

```
SumIf(Range("D1:D20"), """*" & temp & "*""", Range("C1:C20"))
```

Comment: ahh ... this worked. Was wondering what was I missing, triple quotes is the trick. Thanks much

Answer (score 6):

This should do what you want, unless you're looking for something more than just finding basic substrings:

```
Private Sub FindTotal()

    With Sheets("Temp2")
        .Range("N1").Value = Application.SumIf(.Range("D1:D20"), _
                              "*" & .Range("M1").Value & "*", _
                            .Range("C1:C20"))
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For looping concepts, Tim's code can be modified as

```
Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet

For rowIndex = 2 To lastRow
 calcFormula = Application.SumIf(WorkSheet.Range("B:B"), _
                          "*" & Worksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "Q").Value & "*", _
                        WorkSheet.Range("L:L"))
        Worksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "AS").Value = calcFormula  ' output column
Next rowIndex
```